# Bluetooth not working on an Alienware m14x r2

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, firmware

on my alienware m14x r2 laptop with ubuntu 12.04.1 x64, 
the bluetooth interface is not working. WLAN works fine.

I have a dualboot install with ubuntu & win 7 on this laptop.
In win 7, the bluetooth interface works fine, because its all activated
in BIOS.

I have the killer wireless-n 1202 a/g/n interface with integrated 
bluetooth 4.0 in this laptop.

Here is some code :

```
sudo rfkill list

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

lsusb

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:8128 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 187c:0521 Alienware Corporation 

dmesg | grep "Bluetooth"

[    2.590377] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[    2.590395] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.590397] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.590399] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.590403] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.591518] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    2.591519] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    2.599411] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    2.599415] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    2.599416] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    2.696552] Bluetooth: Generic Bluetooth USB driver ver 0.6
[    2.696751] Bluetooth: Atheros AR30xx firmware driver ver 1.0
[    2.702607] Bluetooth: Configuration file not found ar3k/ramps_0x11020000_40.dfu
[    2.702609] Bluetooth: Loading sysconfig file failed
```

Any ideas to fix that problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
[    2.702607] Bluetooth: Configuration file not found ar3k/ramps_0x11020000_40.dfu
```

The file is present in the latest kernel-firmware from OpenSuSE and several other distributions but ubuntu doesn't have it.
As this file is a configuration file, albeit not a plain-text one, I suggest you an experiment: get [this](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:/12.3/standard/noarch/kernel-firmware-20130114git-1.2.1.noarch.rpm) package from openSuSE, extract it, find the file you're missing (as your dmesg says) and place it in `/lib/firmware/ar3k/` directory (don't forget to change permissions and ownership, should be the same as other files in that directory).
Alternatively download the missing file from the [kernel repository](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/ar3k) itself.

Unfortunately I can't verify that this solution will work, as I don't have Ubuntu anywhere within my grasp.